# simple R Time Series function plotting

Tags: r, plot, time-series

thank you kindly for your time.

I'm merely trying to plot a simple time series data set, but am running into a number of basic issues (one of which I'll ask here). For example, I have a notepad file that starts with:

```
"x"   
"1",2.731   
"2",2.562   
"3",2.632   
"4",2.495   
"5",1.978
```

...and so on...

So R reads it just fine, e.g. `myfile=read.table("F:/Documents/myfile.txt",sep="")`. However, the values seem to change under a conversion using R's ts function, i.e.

```
myfile = ts(myfile,start=1,end=120,frequency=1)

plot(myfile, type="o",pch=22,lty=1,pty=2,xlab="Month",ylab="Values",main="My File")
```

So when plotted, the first value starts at 20+ for some reason, as opposed to 2+. Furthermore, R assumes that the y-axis goes from 1 to 120 (mirroring the x-axis), which is not the right scale (i.e. 0 through 10). In another data set that I did (using integers), it was shifted upward by 1. In any event, I believe the issue is probably about how to properly identifying the y-axis.

Any ideas on how to tackle this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm very surprised your happy with how you're reading the data in. Your file example looks to be comma separated, but you tell R the separation character is nothing `sep = ""`. When I try that on your file example, my values are `,2.731`, `,2.562`, which is probably interpreted as a factor...

Comment: You should either specify `sep = ","` or use `read.csv`. This will give you a data.frame. You only want to run `ts` on a single column, `ts(myfile[, 1])`.Then, if you still have problems, post `dput(head(myfile))` so we can see the R structure of what you're working with.

Comment: I thought that sep argument seemed a bit out of place. Anyhow, you're a life-saver!